# Why am I getting errSecParam (-50) back from trying to save a key to keychain?

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

I have the following code following this [storing_keys_in_the_keychain](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/keys/storing_keys_in_the_keychain).

```
func generateInitialKey() -> Data {
    let key = AES256.randomKey()
    let addQuery: Dictionary<String, Any> = [
        kSecClass as String: kSecClassKey,
        kSecAttrApplicationTag as String: applicationTag,
        kSecValueRef as String: key
    ]
    let status = SecItemAdd(addQuery as CFDictionary, nil)
    print(errSecParam, status)
    guard status == errSecSuccess else { fatalError("Can't save Key") }
    return key
}
```

The function `AES256.randomKey()` generates `Data` of 64 bytes. The `applicationTag` is `Data` too:

```
let applicationTag = "example".data(using: .utf8)!
```

However, I do end up receiving the `errSecParam(-50)` error. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/keys/generating_new_cryptographic_keys) carefully. `errSecParam(-50)` means one or more parameters passed to the function were [not valid](https://osstatus.com/search/results?platform=all&framework=all&search=-50). The link leads you to the site where you can see the description of the status.

> At a minimum, you specify the type and size of keys to create using the `kSecAttrKeyType` and `kSecAttrKeySizeInBits` parameters, respectively.

This will result in you having the next problem: there is no `kSecAttrKeyTypeAES`. This is already discussed and answered on the [Apple developer forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/113321). The advice there is to use `kSecClassGenericPassword`.